# Reading in a txt file in SAS

Tags: sas

I am trying to read in a txt file into SAS. The following is my code. I am suppose to have 13 rows and 5 columns. My output is only 6 rows.

```
data Voter_Population;
length Year 4 Voting_age_Population $11
Voter_Registration $11
Turnout $11
Turnout_Percent 4;
infile "&path\Voter Population.txt" dlm="\t" dsd;
input   Year 1-4 Voting_age_Population $6-17
       Voter_Registration $18-29
       Turnout $31-42
       Turnout_Percent 46-48;
```

run;

This is what my dataset looks like. 
I do not want to use `datalines`.

```
1964    114,090,000 73,715,818  70,644,592  61.9
1968    120,328,186 81,658,180  73,211,875  60.8
1972    140,776,000 97,328,541  77,718,554  55.2
1976    152,309,190 105,037,986 81,555,789  53.6
1980    164,597,000 113,043,734 86,515,221  52.6
1984    174,466,000 124,150,614 92,652,680  53.1
1988    182,778,000 126,379,628 91,594,693  50.1
1992    189,529,000 133,821,178 104,405,155 55.1
1996    196,511,000 146,211,960 96,456,345  49.1
2000    205,815,000 156,421,311 105,586,274 51.3
2004    221,256,931 174,800,000 122,294,978 55.3
2008    231,229,580 0       132,618,580 56.8
2012    240,926,957 0       130,234,600 53.6
```

Can someone help me. 
This is what I am getting out

```
    Year    Voting_age_Population   Voter_Registration  Turnout Turnout_Percent
1964    "4  114,090,0"  "   73,715,818" 70,644,592  1968
1972    "2  140,776,0"  "   97,328,541" 77,718,554  1976
1980    "0  164,597,0"  "   113,043,73" "   86,515,221" 52.6
1984    "4  174,466,0"  "   124,150,61" "   92,652,680" 53.1
1988    "8  182,778,0"  "   126,379,62" "   91,594,693" 50.1
1992    "2  189,529,0"  "   133,821,17" "   104,405,15" "   55."
1996    "6  196,511,0"  "   146,211,96" "   96,456,345" 49.1
2000    "0  205,815,0"  "   156,421,31" "   105,586,27" "   51."
2004    "4  221,256,9"  "   174,800,00" "   122,294,97" "   55."
```

Comment: Use the `comma12.0` informat for fields 2, 3 and 4.

Comment: Just w comment re your question. Datelines is typically used to demonstrate an idea, or generate sample data. Saying you don't want to use data lines doesn't make sense.

Comment: The problem is your file is tab delimited and you are using column input.  Delimited files DSD must be read using "list" input.  Get rid of the column ranges in the input statement.

Answer (score 0):

First, you may be misunderstanding what the LENGTH statement does.  It is the number of bytes of storage for the variable.  Numerics default to 8 bytes (Double Precision Floating Point).  For character variables, it is the number of characters unless you are using a Double Byte Character Set (DBCS).

By defining lengths with a $ - Voting_age_Population, Voter_Registration, Turnout - you are forcing those variables to be character and not numeric.  All of your data appears to be numeric.  If they are stored as character fields, you will not be able to use them for Mean, Mode, Max, Standard Deviation, or anything else numeric.

Chris J. is correct in that you should use a COMMA12. informat for fields 2-4.  Furthermore, you don't need to specify the starting and ending columns if there is whitespace between the fields.

```
INPUT Year 4. Voting_age_Population COMMA12. Voter_Registration COMMA12. Turnout COMMA12. Turnout_Percent 4.1 ;
```

should give you numeric values you can then run statistical tests on.

Comment: Joe,The OP likely used $ informats to keep the commas from acting as separators.  Once you change to COMMA informat, you're fine.  There is no need for truncover or missover or specifying the delimiter.  All 13 lines in the data have five numeric values.

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of the other issues Ludwig points out, the specific reasons you're having trouble is that you're not inputting the data correctly.

First off, your data line length is not long enough for your input statement.  That means, by default, SAS will head on to the next line and read it in from there - a big problem, since your data doesn't actually do that.  (It used to commonly do that, but not much anymore.)  You should add `TRUNCOVER` or `MISSOVER` to the `infile` statement in order to get that behavior (where SAS doesn't continue to the next line).

Second off, you clearly have delimited data, not fixed-width data.  Unless you're misleading us, anyway, with the data paste.  It looks like tab-delimited.  That means you shouldn't be specifying column locations - because they may shift (for example, some of your populations are not 11 digits long - in fact most of them are not).  You seem to know it's delimited - but you don't actually use proper delimited (list) input.  And, you have the wrong delimiter - "\t" isn't right.

The right way to do this is to use INFORMAT (like below), correct your delimiter, and use list input.

```
data Voter_Population;
  informat   /* informat is what tells SAS how to read variables in - not length */
  Year 4.
  Voting_age_Population $12. /* or COMMA12. to become numeric*/
  Voter_Registration $12.  /* same */
  Turnout $12. /* same*/
  Turnout_Percent 4.  /* I would make this longer - what if you have 100% turnout? */
  ;  

  infile "&path\Voter Population.txt" dlm="09"x /* right for tab delimiter */ dsd truncover;
  input   
    Year 
    Voting_age_Population $
    Voter_Registration $
    Turnout $
    Turnout_Percent
  ;
run;
```